# How to open a file in assembler and modify it?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm starting to learn Assembler and I'm working in Unix. I want to open a file and write   'Hello world' on it.

```
section .data

textoutput db 'Hello world!', 10
lentext equ $ - textoutput
filetoopen db 'hi.txt'

section .text
global _start

_start:

mov eax, 5            ;open
mov ebx, filetoopen
mov ecx, 2            ;read and write mode
int 80h

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, filetoopen   ;I'm not sure what do i have to put here, what is the "file descriptor"?
mov ecx, textoutput
mov edx, lentext

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h              ; finish without errors
```

But when I compile it, it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?
When I open a file where does the file descriptor value return to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is x86 Linux (x86 is not the only assembly language, and Linux is not the only Unix!)...

```
section .data

textoutput db 'Hello world!', 10
lentext equ $ - textoutput
filetoopen db 'hi.txt'
```

The filename string requires a 0-byte terminator: `filetoopen db 'hi.txt', 0`

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

mov eax, 5            ;open
mov ebx, filetoopen
mov ecx, 2            ;read and write mode
```

`2` is the `O_RDWR` flag for the `open` syscall.  If you want the file to be created if it doesn't already exist, you will need the `O_CREAT` flag as well; and if you specify `O_CREAT`, you need a third argument which is the permissions mode for the file.  If you poke around in the C headers, you'll find that `O_CREAT` is defined as `0100` - beware of the leading zero: this is an octal constant!  You can write octal constants in `nasm` using the `o` suffix.

So you need something like `mov ecx, 0102o` to get the right flags and `mov edx, 0666o` to set the permssions.

```
int 80h
```

The return code from a syscall is passed in `eax`.  Here, this will be the file descriptor (if the open succeeded) or a small negative number, which is a negative `errno` code (e.g. -1 for `EPERM`).  Note that the convention for returning error codes from a raw syscall is *not* quite the same as the C syscall wrappers (which generally return `-1` and set `errno` in the case of an error)...

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, filetoopen   ;I'm not sure what do i have to put here, what is the "file descriptor"?
```

...so here you need to `mov ebx, eax` first (to save the `open` result before `eax` is overwritten) then `mov eax, 4`.  (You might want to think about checking that the result was positive first, and handling the failure to open in some way if it isn't.)

```
mov ecx, textoutput
mov edx, lentext
```

Missing `int 80h` here.

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h              ; finish without errors
```

Comment: Great answer! I just wanted to mention that the flags for open can be found in `/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h` on debian/ubuntu, [here's a gist of the constants](https://gist.github.com/Zhangerr/6022492)

Comment: Excuse me but how do I have to assemble and run this in the linux terminal bcs with `nasm -f elf my_code.asm` `ld -m elf_i386 my_code.o -s -o my_code`  `mycode` does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [Linux Assembly HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)? It covers your question.

You can also compile some C code with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O1` and look at the generated assembly. For example, with `foo.c`, run `gcc -S -Wall -fverbose-asm -O1 foo.c` (as a command in some terminal) then look (using some editor -perhaps [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) into the generated `foo.s` assembler file.

At last, I don't think it is worth bothering a lot about assembler. In 2020, a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler will surely generate better code than what you could write (if you [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) with optimizations, at least `-O2`). See [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a x64 Linux sample

```
; Program to open and write to file
; Compile with:
;     nasm -f elf64 -o writeToFile64.o writeToFile64.asm
; Link with:
;     ld -m elf_x86_64 -o writeToFile64 writeToFile64.o
; Run with:
;     ./writeToFile64
;==============================================================================
; Author : Rommel Samanez
;==============================================================================
global _start

%include 'basicFunctions.asm'

section .data
  fileName:  db "testFile.txt",0
  fileFlags: dq 0102o         ; create file + read and write mode
  fileMode:  dq 00600o        ; user has read write permission
  fileDescriptor: dq 0
section .rodata    ; read only data section
  msg1: db "Write this message to the test File.",0ah,0
  msglen equ $ - msg1
  msg2: db "File Descriptor=",0

section .text
_start:
    mov rax,2               ;   sys_open
    mov rdi,fileName        ;   const char *filename
    mov rsi,[fileFlags]       ;   int flags
    mov rdx,[fileMode]        ;   int mode
    syscall
    mov [fileDescriptor],rax
    mov rsi,msg2
    call print
    mov rax,[fileDescriptor]
    call printnumber
    call printnewline
    ; write a message to the created file
    mov rax,1                 ; sys_write
    mov rdi,[fileDescriptor]
    mov rsi,msg1
    mov rdx,msglen
    syscall
    ; close file Descriptor
    mov rax,3                 ; sys_close
    mov rdi,[fileDescriptor]
    syscall


    call exit
```

Comment: Why would you want to store the flags / mode in `.data` as qword integers?  You could use `equ` the same way you are for `msglen` to define them there but assemble into mov-immediate.  Also, normally you should use mode = `0666o` and let the user's `umask` take care of permissions, so they have the choice of `644` or 664`, or of `600` if they want.

Comment: There's also no reason to store the file descriptor to memory at all.  You could copy it to a call-preserved register (e.g. `ebx`) so it survives function calls that clobber RAX.  Or to `edi` if your `print` function uses a custom calling convention like Irvine32 that preserves RDI. (BTW, `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);` returns an int, which is only 32 bits in the x86-64 System V ABI.  It's pointless to copy around the whole 64-bit register when you only need `eax`.  Also, this answer apparently depends on some `basicFunctions.asm` which you haven't even linked to.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what assembler you are using and if you expect to be using the C runtime or not. In this case which appears to be the Hello World text example from [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Text#X86_Assembly) they are using nasm. Given you have a _start field you are not needing the C runtime so you assemble this to an elf object file and link it into a program:

```
nasm -felf hello.asm
ld hello.o -o hello
```

Now you can run the `hello` program.

A slightly more portable example that uses the C runtime to do the work rather than linux syscalls might look like the sample below. If you link this as described it can use `printf` to do the printing.

```
;;; helloworld.asm -
;;;
;;; NASM code for Windows using the C runtime library
;;;
;;; For windows - change printf to _printf and then:
;;;   nasm -fwin32 helloworld.asm
;;;   link -subsystem:console -out:helloworld.exe -nodefaultlib -entry:main
;;;       helloworld.obj msvcrt.lib
;;; For gcc (linux, unix etc):
;;;   nasm -felf helloworld.asm
;;;   gcc -o helloworld helloworld.o

        extern printf

        section .data
message:
        db 'Hello, World', 10, 0

        section .text
        global main
main:
        push    dword message   ; push function parameters
        call    printf          ; call C library function
        add     esp, 4          ; clean up the stack
        mov     eax, 0          ; exit code 0
        ret
```

For information about file descriptors - read the `open(2)` manual page or look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_%28system_call%29). It is how posix refers to an open i/o stream. In your case, stdout.

Comment: You need `fopen` / `fprintf` to write to a file.  (Or more simply, `fputs` if you don't need formatting.)  Or you need to make `open` and `dup2` system calls to redirect your `stdout` to the file before using stdio `printf`.  Writing asm that uses more portable APIs seems pointless when the calling convention is platform-specific (like for x86-64).  32-bit Windows and Linux calling conventions are close enough for most things, except Windows uses `_printf` in 32-bit code, doesn't it?  But you forgot to ensure 16-byte stack alignment before the `call`; i386 System V requires that. (`sub esp,8`)