# Assembly IA32 - open() implementation

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

Need to implement the system call open(char* string, int flag) with assembly to open a file in WRITE-APPEND mode. So the int flag would be the bitwiseOR of O_WRONLY|O_APPEND.

ebx - will contain the memory address of the string (the pathname of the file to open).

ecx - will contain an integer that is the result of O_WRONLY|O_APPEND.

al - will contain the system call number of open() that is 5.

How to compute  O_WRONLY|O_APPEND  to fill in ecx?

Comment: Check the docs/header files for the numerical values of those constants and calculate the final value by ORing them together. My trick to find those definitions fast is to google `#define` plus the constant I'm looking for, e.g. `#define O_WRONLY`

Comment: Note that the whole of EAX needs to be the call number.  You can't leave garbage in the high bytes because the kernel uses the whole EAX to index its table of call numbers.

Comment: [How to open a file in assembler and modify it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312290) mentions `/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h` in comments.